# REST API refresh filter list

Tags: rest-api, mobileconnect, refresh

I used REST API to refresh a filter list in mobileconnect ([taken from the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postRefreshSMSAudience.htm)). The filter list is refreshed successfully but the tokenId i get are always the same.

I tried to use that tokenId with another REST API command to check the refresh status ([based on this code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getRefreshSMSAudience.htm)) but always got an error said:

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

```
{"documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm","errorcode":404,"message":"Not Found"}
```

I think that's because the tokenId is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first command and api are correct but the second code on salesforce website is not correct:

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com

GET /sms/v1/contacts/refreshList/ENGam1FZUtNX0p/status/NDo8NDow

Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```